# SQL Azure Catch Storage Max Size Error?

Tags: azure, data-access-layer, azure-sql-database

I am working on a database on a local SQL Server 2012 instance with a plan to migrate it to Azure after it has been tested/used locally. The .NET data access layer code has multiple catch{} blocks, but I also want to catch the error when the database has exceeded its maximum size. What is the exact error Type that is raised, and what is the smartest way to catch it? I will want to send an email to admins if this occurs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to check the number on the exception:

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (SqlException sqlException)
{
    switch (sqlException.Number)
    {
        // The database has reached its size quota. Partition or delete data,
        // drop indexes, or consult the documentation for possible resolutions. 
        case 40544:
            break;
    }
}
```

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/10/10048453.aspx